# What role does the NASA deputy administrator play?

Tags: nasa

[A new deputy NASA administrator](https://www.nasa.gov/press-release/statements-on-senate-confirmation-of-dava-newman-as-nasa-deputy-administrator), Dava Newman, has been appointed. What is the actual function of a deputy administrator in NASA? What kind of decisions will she be responsible for? And is a deputy likely to become the next top boss?

Answer (score 3):

Dava Newman will, on the week of May 18 when she'll be sworn in, succeed Lori Garver, that was previous NASA Deputy Administrator till September 2013. So the answer to the latter part of your question, if *deputy is likely to become the next top boss*, is no, not necessary, but it wouldn't be unheard of;

Garver is now the General Manager of the Air Line Pilots Association, and leads Obama Presidential Transition Agency Review Team for NASA. One previous Deputy Administrator however later became NASA Administrator - Dr. Thomas O. Paine (Deputy from March 25, 1968 to March 20, 1969, Acting Administrator from October 8, 1968 to March 21, 1969 and then Administrator from March 21, 1969 to September 15, 1970).

And for the first part, it would be easiest to appreciate Deputy Administrator's role if we analyzed Garver's work while she held that position (July 17, 2009 to September 6, 2013). According to NASA's [Lori B. Garver, NASA Deputy Administrator](https://www.nasa.gov/about/highlights/garver_bio.html) page:

> As deputy administrator, Garver is NASA's second in command. She works
>   closely with the administrator to provide overall leadership,
>   planning, and policy direction for the agency. Together with the NASA
>   administrator, Garver represents NASA to the Executive Office of the
>   President, Congress, heads of government agencies, international
>   organizations, and external organizations and communities. She also
>   oversees the work of NASA's functional offices.

NASA Administrator Charles Bolden also urged US Senate during last few hearings to approve Newman as he needs help. So it's not merely a prestige position to climb the rungs from. Newman can expect a lot of work ahead.

If you want to compare which Deputy Administrators became NASA Administrators, here's [a list of all of them on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Administrators_and_Deputy_Administrators_of_NASA), since NACA (National Advisory Committee for Aeronautics) became NASA (National Aeronautics and Space Administration).

Comment: Dava Newman is not succeeding Lori Garver. Newman is filling an empty void. Lori Garver resigned in September, 2013. NASA has had no deputy administrator for the 20 month interval between Garver's resignation and Newman's swearing in. NASA doesn't always have a deputy administrator.

Comment: @DavidHammen [Marcia S. Smith](http://www.spacepolicyonline.com/news/newman-to-be-sworn-in-as-nasa-deputy-administrator-in-mid-may) and I disagree with you. But that's semantics. The position that Newman will occupy was last occupied by Garver, tho granted, there was time during which that position remained unoccupied. Note that I didn't say that Newman will _replace_ Garver (dates I add make that obvious). Actually, Garver absolutely approves of Newman taking that position and commented with _[You go girl!](https://twitter.com/search?q=%40Lori_Garver%20Newman%20you%20go%20girl)_ on Twitter.

Comment: Interesting answer, thanks. But what are the deputy's actual responsibilities? Just a talker and advisor, or does a NASA deputy have some specific task, like leading human spaceflight or the heliophysics or something?

Comment: @LocalFluff See David Hammen's answer. It depends, but Newman should have very similar responsibilities than Garver did, because she'll also start serving as a deputy to Bolden (administrator since July 17, 2009), same as Garver. There's currently also Republicans proposed bill ([H.R. 2093](http://www.spacepolicyonline.com/pages/images/stories/Space%20Leadership%20Act%20of%202015.pdf)) to extend the NASA Administrator position to 10-year appointment and depoliticize NASA with _Space Leadership Preservation Act_. So it might be that Newman will be a deputy to Bolden for quite some time.

Comment: @TildalWave - Only if a Democrat is elected as President next year, and only if the incoming Democratic President chooses to keep Bolden and Newman onboard. (The odds a Republican President would keep the current team onboard are essentially zero.) Otherwise, she will serve as deputy for less than two years.

Comment: @TildalWave - I doubt that that legislation is aimed at Bolden. I strongly suspect it's in anticipation that a Republican will be elected as President next year.

Comment: So it is up to the administrator to make up any task for his deputy? Like going on with the space suite engineering, or trying to get a handle on that space station nightmare, or making something up about how we could get a boot on Mars? Is in the American tradition a "deputy" generally a *"Sonderbevollmächtigten des Führers"*, who has sweeping powers, like how Adolf Hitler used that concept in line with his Führerprinzip? (sorry for the probably wrong German grammar there)

Answer (score 3):

> What is the actual function of a deputy administrator in NASA? What kind of decisions will she be responsible for?

That depends very much on the administrator and how he (they've all been "he" so far) delegates things. Deputy administrator is a political appointment. Sometimes the administrator doesn't like the person foisted on him, and the role is meaningless. Other times, the administrator delegates a lot to his deputy.

> And is a deputy likely to become the next top boss?

The deputy has become the acting administrator six times. Acting administrator is a placeholder position. Someone needs to be in charge. As an acting administrator, what they do had better not be anything of consequence. A deputy who became the official administrator: That's happened but once.

The administrator and deputy administrator are the only two political appointments in NASA. When the party of the President changes, the incoming President typically accepts the resignation of the NASA administrator and deputy administrator. How those transitions work vary a lot from administration to administration.  Sometimes the President takes his time to get around to dealing with NASA; NASA is a rather small and unimportant government agency from the President's perspective.